# Maven dependencies in a Mule project . Classloader control not working as expected

Tags: java, maven, junit, mule, mule-studio

I'm trying to build a mule project in maven which uses a library that in turn uses `apache-commons-codec-1.8` . Mule 3.5 currently supports only v `1.3`

In order to get around this Ive implemented classloader control in mule and blocked mule from loading its version of the library by doing the following in `mule-deploy.properties`.

`loader.override=-org.apache.commons.codec`

In addition I've updated my `pom.xml` to include the `1.9` version of the library . Here is a snapshot of running `mvn:dependency tree` on the project. 
[image: mvn:depedency tree]
However, when I run my test method I get a runtime exception

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString([B)Ljava/lang/String;
    at com.nimbusds.jose.util.Base64URL.encode(Base64URL.java:64)
    at com.nimbusds.jose.util.Base64URL.encode(Base64URL.java:91)
    at com.nimbusds.jose.Header.toBase64URL(Header.java:238)
    at com.nimbusds.jose.JWSObject.<init>(JWSObject.java:101)
    at com.package.components.lastmile.originator.TokenSignerTemplate.sign(TokenSignerTemplate.java:109)
    at com.package.components.lastmile.originator.TokenSignerTemplate.signClaim(TokenSignerTemplate.java:122)
    at com.package.orchestration.LMSFakeClaimsHandler.testSignParse_Positive(LMSFakeClaimsHandler.java:120)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
```

which is clearly because it's referencing the older version of `apache-commons`. How do I make sure that it references only the latest version and not the older version?

**mule-deploy.properties**

```
#Fri Dec 12 09:58:12 PST 2014
loader.override=-org.apache.commons.codec
redeployment.enabled=true
encoding=UTF-8
domain=default
config.resources=..flows.
```

.

Relevant positions of **pom.xml**

```
<dependencies>
....
<dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>


....
    <!-- Test to check commons-codec works -->
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-transport-http</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

**P.S: The same snippet seems to work fine on a non mule project, indicating this is a mule related issue.**

Answer (score 0):

Add the following exclusion to your pom.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-transport-http</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

And then add the dependency of Commons Codec 1.9.
Then your override property in mule-deploy.properties will work as expected.

Update: 12/30:
The override property seems to be the problem.

```
loader.override=-org.apache.commons.codec   is not correct.
```

Try the following

```
loader.override=org.apache.commons.codec
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nope . Doesnt work . I added the above as part of the dependency tag in addition to the following entry  `<dependency>
   <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
   <version>1.9</version>
  </dependency>`
I get the same error.

Comment: Please add your pom.xml and mule-deploy.properties to the OP. That might help us understand the issue.

Comment: Done. Let me know if you need more info

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the Mule app in Mule server, excluding the lib from the pom will not work, since the codec lib is present in the server itself.

Try to insert the newest codec lib version in the server **lib shared folder** (maintaining the property `loader.override=-org.apache.commons.codec`)

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue with the jackson-xc. I don't know why Mule 3.5 comes with a mix of jackson 1 and 2 libraries

```
jackson-annotations-2.1.1.jar
jackson-core-2.1.1.jar
jackson-databind-2.1.1.jar

jackson-core-asl-1.9.11.jar
jackson-jaxrs-1.9.11.jar
jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.11.jar
jackson-xc-1.7.1.jar
```

And with **jackson-xc-1.7.1** instead of **jackson-xc-1.9.11** that would be aligned to the version of the other **jackson 1** libraries.

In my application it is producing the "classic" library issue exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.AnnotationIntrospector$Pair.findDeserializer(AnnotationIntrospector.java:1335)
```

Since using

```
loader.override=...
```

into the **mule-deploy.properties** didn't work (with either override and/or blocking on the package org.codehaus.jackson.xc and on the class org.codehaus.jackson.xc.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector) the only solution I have found goes in the direction of Nuno's answer and is to put the jar we want to use in a lib folder with higher priority than **lib/opt**

**lib/shared** has been deprecated but you can use **lib/user** to override.

I would prefer to use the **loader.override** ([classloader-control-in-mule 3.5](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.5/classloader-control-in-mule)) and avoid the modification of all the installation, but for now is the only solution that is working for me.